# How to start with meioupload for cake php

Tags: cakephp, meio-upload

i m new to cake php and tried to use meioupload for uploading file.,

searched for a complete steps., but i m not sure whether i read the full docs..

so here i m ., i ll discuss the things i did.,

from this link 
http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/

i created a table named "products"

CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) default NULL,
`description` text default NULL,
`price` double default NULL,
`picture` varchar(255) default NULL,
`dir` varchar(255) default NULL,
`mimetype` varchar(255) NULL,
`filesize` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
`created` datetime default NULL,
`modified` datetime default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) )

And then after adding the "$actAs" var in my model ., it looks like

`

Class product extends AppModel{

```
public $name="Product";

var $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'picture' => array(
            'dir' => 'uploads',
            'create_directory' => true,
            'max_size'=>'10 Mb',
            'allowed_mime' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png'),
            'allowed_ext' => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'),
            'thumbsizes' => array(
                'normal' => array('width'=>200, 'height'=>200),
            ),
            'default' => 'default.jpg',
        )
    )
);
```

}
`

And uploaded MeioUploadBehavior.php file inside Model->Behaviour->MeioUploadBehavior.php from https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload/blob/master/Model/Behavior/MeioUploadBehavior.php

My controller looks like

```
Class productscontroller extends AppController{

public $name="Products";

public function beforeFilter(){

    $this->layout="admin";
}
public function admin_upload(){

}
```

}

And my view file from view->products->admin_upload.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('dir', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('mimetype', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('filesize', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

?>

when i run localhost/test/cake/admin/products/upload

i see the form with filefield ans submit button.,

and when i choose a image and submit., the form is successfully submitted and only a empty folder is created inside webroot->uploads->"thumb". No images moved to uploads and also thumb folder.,

And also there is data inserted in the table as well..

Do i need the save the data manually in my action !?

Kindly help.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like your controller's action is empty. Try saving the data that was submitted from the form using the model's `save()` method. This will trigger MeioUpload to save the file that was uploaded with the form.

It also looks like you're using CakePHP 2.x, I suggest you qualify the plugin as `'MeioUpload.MeioUpload'` in the `$actsAs` property of your model. Make sure you give proper write and execute permissions on the `uploads` folder in your webroot.

Source: I'm building my own website with the MeioUpload plugin.

Comment: Yes i m using CakePHP 2.x.
And as u mention when i save() through my method i saw the entry added in Table and image moved to the "uploads" directory.
But there is no thumbnail generated ., i tried extracting phpThumb into my Vendor folder..but same result..

Comment: Looks like you're all good with the phpThumb vendor. I edited my answer above, did you forget to fix your `uploads` folder permission? Usually it just needs write+execute permissions so the plugin can write the thumbnails properly.

Comment: i m in my localhost only., also tried changing the permission.. no thumbnails generated inside uploads/thumb.
but the original image is attach is perfectly uploaded into the "uploads" folder.

Comment: Was this issue ever answered?  I am having the same issue with no thumbnails being generated.